# Reverting LG GT540 to its old interface

Tags: lg-gt540-optimus

I just tried to install my LG GT540 with a KDZ file that I downloaded from a site, hoping that my problem with the Android Market would be fixed but nothing happened.

My problem is that I can't revert the phone back to its original interface. It now has a Vodafone on the background screen.

Any idea on how I can revert it back?

Comment: What network are you currently using? I'm assuming it's not Vodaphone. You need to use a firmware that is compatible with your network.

Comment: how to know? actually its my mothers phone and i think she bought it at Hongkong a year ago. and yeah, its not a vodaphone it just turned out to be one after installing the firmware.

Comment: What network should be using now?

Comment: i really dont have an idea but im using a local network in my country (its Globe) any idea how i can revert it back i dont like the vodafone background and some icons has changed into vodafone mod..technology is very complicated to me..

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Globe, then I assume you're in the Philippines. (Same here)

Check this out: http://www.droidevelopers.com/f236/11721-%5Bdownload%5D-%5Bfirmware%5D-lg-optimus-gt540-original-roms.html. It has a ROM for Philippines, and instructions on how to install it.